# Sending email in PHP is not working after host change

Tags: php, email, post, smtp, sendmail

I changed the hosting and now the sending of email is not working.
On the old server this two lines where enough to send mail:

```
ini_set("SMTP", "xxx.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
```

Changed the SMTP server to the new one, but when I try to send a mail I got:
[HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 173ms]

What could be the problem?
(Sorry, but I'm new to PHP)

My website is: [link](https://www.albaiuliavaluecentre.ro/)

My new host is: [link](https://www.interserver.net)

Code:

```
<?php

//ini_set("SMTP", "xxx.com");
//ini_set("sendmail_from", "office@xxx.com"); 
//ini_set("smtp_port", "25"); 
$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// MSG SUBJECT
if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
} else {
    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
}


// Price
if (empty($_POST["price"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Price is required ";
} else {
    $price = $_POST["price"];
}


$EmailTo = "office@xxx.com";
$Subject = "✨New Message Received ✨";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "NAME: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "EMAIL: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "SUBJECT: ";
$Body .= $msg_subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "PRICE: ";
$Body .= $price;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "DOMAIN: ";
$Body .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I would imaging few hosting co's still use port25 for mail. Also all now insist the the FROM address is an address that exists within their mail server to help reduce spam, by that is mean a from address like `aaaaa@xxx.com` using your example. You appear to be using the clients email address as the from address.

Comment: Instead set the `reply to` to the clients address and use `office@xxx.com` as the from address

Comment: @RiggsFolly this will be used as a contact form - when someone makes a bid, I should get that bid on my office@xxx.com mail and the "from" should be the sender of the bid

Comment: Except if the hosting company is a decent one, they will NOT ALLOW you to send email using a from address other than one that exists for this domain. So as I say use the `ReplyTo:` for the other persons email and then you will still know their email address

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" is not the real error. You'll need to look for that in the server logs. There's typically a log viewer in your control panel.

Comment: I managed to send the mail, but on yahoo I get: `Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:    ecclesiasoft@yahoo.com Technical details of permanent failure:
550 5.7.1 [SHF] Message rejected. See https://console.mailchannels.net/insights/bounce?auid=interserver&sender=office%40albavaluecentre.ro&txid=3e7657b60f66177c`